# What is the probability that I choose a card at position i of a deck, shuffle that deck and the i-th card is the same as before?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, card-games

I have a deck on $n$ cards and choose the $i$-th card of the deck. After looking at the card I put it back and shuffle the deck. What is the probability, that the $i$-th card is the same as before.

My thoughts so far/what I (think) I know:

- I have $n!$ possible permutations of the deck.
- Selecting one card that doesn't permute reduces the number of possible permutations to $(n-1)!$

This leaves me thinking that, with selecting position $i$ with a probability of $1/n$, the probability that the card stays the same simply results in $P[\text{position i doesn't change}]=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Which I somehow don't believe, especially after studying [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/04/06/subfactorial/) that the probability that the probability that exactly one card stays on the same position is $\frac{1}{n!}\binom{n}{k}\lfloor\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}\rfloor$ which is kind of more complicated than my solution which I guess is kind of related.

Any help and hint is much appreciated!

Comment: This problem is different from the linked problem in that you are only requiring a particular card to be in the same position as before, not that it is the only card that is in the same position that it was before.

Comment: For your problem, you have chosen *some* card. You only want that this card should appear in the same position after reshuffling, so the probability is merely $\large\frac 1{n}$

Comment: thanks for your comments, at first I had the thought about the probability being $frac{1}{n}$ but got kind of distracted from the problem in the link that as @N.F.Taussig summarized that is different from mine. So thank you both